# SQL Query on a Datatable or List of entity

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datatable

I have a DataTable that is being generated at runtime with values from an Excel sheet.

My question: is there a way you can run a SQL query against the data in the data table so that it can return data?

```
var dt = datatable.select("select col1,col2 from dt");
```

I would be getting the query in the brackets as a parameter.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1849449.aspx?How+to+use+select+query+on+datatable+in+C+

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/querying-a-data-table-using-select-method-and-lambda-express/

Comment: Thank you for the response but using this i cannot pass the direct sql command to query the datatable. i was looking to send the sql command to the select like extension method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a method that does exactly what you want. You can use the `DataTable` `Select` method like so:

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select();

foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr["col1"]);
    Console.WriteLine(dr["col2"]);
}
```

Ref: [DataTable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: thank you Mitch Wheat. looks like there is no direct way of passing sql command to Select method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use it as a CTE?

```
With YOUR_CTE AS (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, FROM TABLE
)
SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TABLE
WHERE WHATEVER = (SELECT COL1 FROM YOUR_CTE)
```

Comment: May be you didnt understood my question. i have a datatable object already after reading an excel sheet. now i would like to query it from pure sql command like we have this feature using dataframe in python where in you can send a pure sql command to dataframe